# How to set custom status codes in error with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

Hi i need to throw custom errors with custom status.The response status should be always 200 /201.Please help me to reslove this issue.Current status in given below

`{
  "timestamp": "2017-03-30T05:59:56.010+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "custom exception",
  "message": "custom message",
  "path": "/api/sjsdj"
}`
What i expect as response is

`{
  "timestamp": "2017-03-30T05:59:56.010+0000",
  "status": 600,
  "error": "custom error",
  "exception": "web.rest.errors.custom exception",
  "message": "custom message",
  "path": "/api/hgdsh/3"
}`

Comment: check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236811/spring-boot-customize-http-error-response), especially the answer from Geoff Bourne. might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler`.

Create a `@ControllerAdvice` with methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` that cache your custom exceptions / generic one and return your custom status/message etc there.

Example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleControllerException(HttpServletRequest req, Throwable ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```