# Customize Spring Boot error response code without changing the default body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

Spring Boot by default returns a response body for exceptions that meets my needs out of the box:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1587794161453,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException",
    "message": "No resource exists for the given ID",
    "path": "/my-resource/1"
}
```

However, I would like to customize the response code for different types of exceptions thrown by my application.  Some of the exceptions are not ones I own, so I can't just stick a `@ResponseStatus` annotation on the exception class.  I've tries using an `@ExceptionHandler` method with `@ResponseStatus`, but that is overwriting the response body, which I don't wish to happen.  For instance, I would like to map `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` to return status code 404.

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public void handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException e) {
    // This method returns an empty response body
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236811/spring-boot-customize-http-error-response) is similar to mine, but it is also attempting to adjust the response body.  I am hoping that there is a shorter, more idiomatic way of adjusting just the status code and not the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449450/1108305) to the question I mentioned had the exact solution needed to solve this problem, even though it didn't quite fully the question asked.  The trick was dropping the use of `@ResponseStatus` from the method, and manually setting the status on the `HttpServletResponse` using [`HttpServletResponse.sendError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int)).  This serves the standard Spring Boot exception response, but with the updated status code.

```
@ExceptionHandler
public void handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

```
{
    "timestamp": 1587794161453,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException",
    "message": "No resource exists for the given ID",
    "path": "/my-resource/1"
}
```