# MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException - custom error message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app which returns JSON.

In one of its methods, it has an `Integer` parameter (@RequestParam).

While doing security testing they called my method with some JS code passed in
(instead of an integer value).

```
2021-07-01 04:59:14.995  WARN [tpe-rcf,2ff110026bf0649e,2ff110026bf0649e,false] 12800 
--- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :   
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:   
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer';    
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<script>alert(11355545)</script>"]
```

I am getting this error above in the console of my app.

This is then sent to the browser in some JSON which looks like this:

```
{

... 

"message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"<script>alert(11355545)</script>\"",

"path": "/a/b/c"

}
```

My question is if it's possible to override the error message e.g. by replacing the `<` with `\u003c` in the JSON that's returned to the browser.

The security testers claim I should sanitize the JSON returned (i.e. escape these `<` symbols) since that may pose some issues for older browsers (i.e. get this JS code executed in them).

But it's the SpringBoot framework who generates the error message,
I have no much control here.

Of course I can define the parameter as String and do the validation myself but I doubt that is the right way. My parameter is defined as Integer and I prefer it stays that way.

So my question is how to do this escaping/sanitizing? I tried using `@ControllerAdvice` and override `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` but no much luck so far.

I think if there's a way it should be quite simple.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot customize http error response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236811/spring-boot-customize-http-error-response)

Comment: It seems what you are after is hadling DefaultErrorAttributes. There is a similar answer on SOF. I have shared the link above. Maybe, it is what you need. If not, you can let me know. I will try implementing some custom project to handle your use-case.

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Indeed Seems very close to what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why is @ControllerAdvice not working for you

This works perfectly fine for returning custom messages

```
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"your.package"})
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler  {
    
    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException .class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ResponseEntity<FooBarErrorEntity> methodArgumentTypeMismatchException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new FooBarErrorEntity(message, path),
                                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Where FooBarErrorEntity can be your custom error entity, where you have the same attributes you'd expect normally
Also you can parse the message and do the 'sanitizing' within the constructor of the ErrorEntity which would remove the duplicate code in case of more exceptions to handle

Comment: Thanks but I need a generic handler like that which would sanitize all error messages regardless if MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException  or of some other type.

Comment: @peter.petrov Do you want to unveil the error in the user or you want to hide it. What is your requirement in the end? What do you mean by generic aproach? What message would you want to deliver genericaly?

Comment: @peter.petrov you could create two controller advices. One with highest precedence and one with normal priority. In the former insert all the exceptions you want to handle in a custom way. On the latter just add as ExceptionHandler the generic Exception. This way no matter what it's going to get filtered out + you'll have to modify for some specific exceptions